# build a new proxyv2 image？

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

how do I build a new proxyv2 image as some of the envoy code modified? It seems that the official documentation does not have a particularly detailed introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the Istio Github repo's:  https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Using-the-Code-Base